# How to force delete an MWAA environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, cost-management, mwaa

I have updated some Airflow configuration options in my MWAA environment and it has been in "Updating" state for the last three hours!

Does anybody know how to force-delete that environment? Using the "Delete" button on the AWS MWAA console only leads to a "Environments with UPDATING status must complete previous operation before initiating a new operation" message.

Answer (score 4):

You **cannot force delete** MWAA environment that has Updating or Creating statuses. You will get a warning like `Environments with … status must complete the previous operation before initiating a new operation`.

The reason of a stuck environment update operation is an **improper configuration**. You have to fix it.

When en environment is created or updated, **MWAA service [polls](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/tree/master/MWAA) the environment to validate its configuration**, e.g. web UI accessibility. Check that your networking is configured properly, following [troubleshooting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/t-create-update-environment.html#t-stuck-failure) and [MWAA networking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/networking-about.html) guides.

In my case the reason was in improper gateways configuration for MWAA environment with public access to web UI: to troubleshoot I have updated public subnet route tables to route `0.0.0.0/0` to an internet gateway instead of NAT gateway (while private subnets should be routed to NAT gateway).

I suggest you to use [official CloudFormation template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/quick-start.html#quick-start-createstack) or [this Terraform module](https://github.com/idealo/terraform-aws-mwaa) to properly configure all the resources.

Another way is to wait for timeout of an operation (several hours). However, it will just give you a link to the troubleshooting doc. **In case you delete and then recreate the environment with improper configuration again, the operation will be stuck again**.

Comment: some time, the case is for improper configuration of a network, nat gateway, route table.
I follow the troubleshooting and MWAA networking guides, but without any success.
All this, using the quick start guide.

Comment: how much time you mean several hours?, I was stuck in creating stage

Comment: @avsr I do not remember exactly, but more than 1 hour for sure. Probably smth around 6.

Comment: yeah, For me, I had the same problem I messed up with VPC setup, It took 4-5 hours